# Kanboard Custom Fields

Tags: php

Customization work regarding [Kanboard](https://kanboard.org/)

I need to add custom fields to the create new task form. Can this be achieved using [Metadata Manager](https://github.com/BlueTeck/kanboard_plugin_metadata) plugin?

Will I need to hire a developer to get this done?

Currently there's only Title, Description & Tags available. I Just need to add three more fields to show in the task box in Kanban view.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, the Metadata plugin will not achieve that. There is a plugin that will allow you to create custom fields that will be included on the create task form, but since you didn't ask, I cannot tell you which plugin (I tried already, and it was downvoted and deleted because it didn't answer your question apparently)

No, you will not need to hire a developer to get this done, assuming you can find the plugin I am referring to.

With said plugin, you will be able to add as many custom fields as you wish, as well as, including them in task exports, filtering, change their type, etc...

Good luck in your search!

Comment: Thanks heaps! I'll look for that plugin